# percentage plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot something like the image below but I have an error of "stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.". So I change it to stat="identity". But the outcome is not the same as the example I found online.

**Example found online:**

example is found from: https://sebastiansauer.github.io/percentage_plot_ggplot2_V2/
[image: example found online]

**My code**

```
  geom_bar(aes(y=pct_change, fill=factor(Year)), stat="count")+
  geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(pct_change),
                 y= pct_change ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
  ylab("Avg Unit Price")  +
  facet_grid(~Type.of.Sale) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the `mtcars` dataset how you could achieve your task:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, group=am))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=..prop.., fill=factor(..x..)), stat="count")+
  geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
                 y= ..prop..), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
  ylab("Avg Unit Price")  +
  facet_grid(~am) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for helping me. however, to use tidyverse package, I can't load dplyr package at the same time or it will show conflict. what should i do so that i can load tidyverse and dplyr at the same time?

Comment: `dplyr` is in `tidyverse`. So if you do `library(tidyverse)` automatically some other packages like `dplyr`, `ggplot`, `tidyr` etc.. are loaded.

Comment: I still have this error though "stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic."

Comment: Please `dput()` your data and add it to your question. Write `dput(hereyourdata)` in the console. And copy and paste the output in your question as edit.